# using cdt eclipse and cygwin to create .so shared object on windows 7

Tags: linux, cygwin, shared-libraries, eclipse-cdt

I have Eclipse CDT installed (juno) on my windows 7 computer
I have cygwin installed (able to manually create a makefile and create a .so)

I want to use the cygwin compiler in eclipse to create a .so

I created a new shared library project in eclipse told it to use the cygwin c++ compiler

do a ctrl-b and it creates a .dll

how do I get it to make a .so?

this is using windows 7

```
11:13:05 **** Build of configuration Debug for project cygwinc++ ****
make all 
Building file: ../main.cpp
Invoking: Cygwin C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "../main.cpp"
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:\Users\EAIGREG\workspace\cygwinc++\Debug
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/Users/EAIGREG/workspace/cygwinc++/Debug
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
Finished building: ../main.cpp

Building target: cygwinc++.dll
Invoking: Cygwin C++ Linker
g++ -shared -o "cygwinc++.dll"  ./main.o   
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:\Users\EAIGREG\workspace\cygwinc++\Debug
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/Users/EAIGREG/workspace/cygwinc++/Debug
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
Finished building target: cygwinc++.dll


11:13:06 Build Finished (took 390ms)
```

clearly this is using the wrong compiler... i know that my cygwin can create SO so how to i tell it to use the "linux" c++ compiler?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there is a way to accomplish what I was looking for, but what I ended up doing was getting another computer running linux...

If I wanted to I could have just manually create my makefile and manually link and compile (maybe a few fancy batch files) but in the end it was just easier to have a full working eclipse environment natively in linux